# Semisimplification of a representation

Tags: representation-theory

1) what is the semisimplification of a representation $\rho:G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$?

When I try googling it, I just find results for semi simple representation, which is one in which every subrepresentation has a complement.If the context matters $G$ is a Galois group and $k$ is a finite field.

2) Two semisimple representations with equal characteristic polynomials are isomorphic. Is this true? I guess

Comment: 1) It's the direct sum of all the composition factors in a composition series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series